# JavaFx Scene Builder PPA Installation

Tags: java, ubuntu

Is there a method to install the JavaFx Scene Builder on Ubuntu via a ppa repository?

Like in this example for the Oracle Java 8:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: it seems that scenebuilder is not part of the installation package. I installed it from deb package available here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Comment: That's unfortunate. I was hoping to apt-get it from a repository :(